# Filter the trigger on parent object based on the record type type on child object

Tags: trigger

I have 2 custom objects with master-detail relationship:

```
custom_object__1(parent)
custom_object__2(child)
```

I have an after update trigger on the Custom_Object__1(parent) and also I have the if condition where the fields are set as criteria based on which the trigger.new is fired now I need to need to include the record type of the child object also  on the filter type any approach on how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to filter parent records based on record type of child records?. There can be multiple child records with different record types under one parent record right?

Comment: You will have to query the child objects including their RecordTypeId field for the set of objects in the trigger. And as @Victor mentions you need to consider how multiple record types for the child objects should affect the logic unless you have already constrained that in some way.

Comment: In this case we have only 1 child all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code of this sort will allow you to use the developer name of the record type in your logic:

```
trigger MyTrigger on custom_object__1 (after update) {

    // Map is custom_object__1 to developer name of custom_object__2 record type
    Map<Id, String> m = new Map<Id, String>();
    for (custom_object__2 c2 : [
            select custom_object__1, RecordType.DeveloperName
            from custom_object__2
            where custom_object__1 in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()
            ]) {
        m.put(c2.custom_object__1, c2.RecordType.DeveloperName);
    }

    for (custom_object__1 c1 : Trigger.new) {
        String developerName = m.get(c1.Id);
        if (developerName == 'xyz') {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```